# GNU make use variable value to call a "function"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to iterate through the list, LIST,  and want to call a function which writes something into a text file using the name of the extracted list elements as name of the call to the "function".

```
.PHONY: GEN_BAT
GEN_BAT:
    for comp in $(basename $(notdir $(LIST))); do \
        echo comp: $$comp ;\
        $(call $$comp)
    done; \
```

If I write the line `$(call $$comp)` without a `;\`  I'll receive "syntax error: unexpected end of file".
If I write the line with the original function e.g. `$(call FUNCTION);\`  with a `;\`  it calls the existing function as expected. So, something is wrong with the used variable?

How can I persuade `make` to use the value of `$$comp` as a call to "function"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a *shell* loop then try to utilize the *shell* loop variable in a *make* function.  If you think about it that doesn't make any sense: the shell is a completely different program than make, make can't know what the shell's variable are set to, and the shell can't call make functions.

Make runs a command like this: *first* the entire recipe is expanded so that ALL make variables and functions are resolved.  Then make takes that expanded command string and gives it to the shell and the shell process it as a shell script.  Make waits for the shell to complete, then reports the exit code as success (0) or failure (not 0).

Also, a statement like `$(call xyz)` makes no real sense in make: calling a function with no arguments is identical to simply expanding the variable as in `$(xyz)`.  The only time `call` makes sense is if you pass arguments to it.

Comment: now I understand my missing link.
As I'm using a shell for loop I'm working inside the shell and not inside the make environment. And as you explain, this two parities doesn't know anything from each other.
Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes.  More specifically, it's one-way: make will expand all its variables, then call the shell with the results.  So make can impact what the shell will run (of course) but nothing that happens in the shell can invoke make functions etc.

Comment: Good explanation. Just would like to add that it is just the make function name that can not be a shell variable (as it is defined as a make variable), which is the case here. The first sentence seems not a bit confusing as shell variable can be used as parameters even if it is expanded later.

Comment: I don't understand what that comment is trying to say.  There's no conflict between make variables and functions and shell variables or syntax.  All make variables and functions are prefixed with `$` and any time you want a `$` to be passed to the shell you escape it via `$$`.  So they are in completely different namespaces.